# SPLIT EACH WORD IN NEW ROW

Tags: google-sheets, split

I used this formula to split each word in different row:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(
 IF(Sheet1!A2:B6000="",,Sheet1!A2:A6000&"×"&SPLIT(Sheet1!B2:B6000, " "))), "×"), 
 )))
```

But it is working only for the first two words in each cell in column A.

How can I update this formula to split all words?

Here is the sheet sample:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wi5neSYC_lb6nRXDRYxMk7tLWCoBpy2VSx7ejXt9yXI/edit?usp=sharing

[this the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SxBGU.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

added formula to your sheet:

```
=QUERY(INDEX(SPLIT(FLATTEN(A2:A100&"|"&BYROW(B2:B100,LAMBDA(bx,SPLIT(bx," ")))),"|",0,0)),"SELECT * WHERE Col2!=''")
```

- 

[image]